# How to map j and k to gj and gk in Emacs Evil-mode?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I would like to map `j` `k` motions in evil to be `gj` and `gk` respectively. This is a common remapping people usually do in vim. How can I do that in Emacs. I guess I just need to find how these Evil functions that correspond to `gj` and `gk` motions are named.

Comment: For any given key binding you can do `C-h k` followed by the binding to find out the name of the command it is bound to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The functions you're looking for are `evil-next-visual-line` and `evil-previous-visual-line`. You can bind them with:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "j") 'evil-next-visual-line)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "k") 'evil-previous-visual-line)
```